# selecting in a loop using a cursor

Tags: mysql

I have got this stored procedure:

```
    DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cursor_example//
CREATE PROCEDURE cursor_example()
BEGIN
    DECLARE niche_id INT;
    DECLARE niche_name VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE curl CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM `niche`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

    OPEN curl;
      my_loop:LOOP
        FETCH curl INTO niche_id,niche_name;
        IF done=1 THEN
           LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;      
      END LOOP my_loop;
    CLOSE curl;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

I want to output everything that the curl fetches. So I thought to put SELECT statement inside or outside the loop..but that wouldnt give me the results that I want. How do I get back all the sql results from that cursor.

And what are the advantages of using cursors compare to other a simple unbound - SELECT statement. I mean I could get the results that I wanted by simply USING  a select statement without writing all that cursor code?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you just want to "output" the data, then why aren't you using a view?  As for your question about cursors, there is no advantage to cursors versus a simple select, if the select meets your needs.

Comment: Too bad that not enough people here know about this subject